# Python Azure Function - System Assigned Identity - Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I have a requirement to use **Azure Managed Identity to connect to Azure SQL from my Azure Function** which is written in Python. But when I am deploying the code below, I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception: OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
Stack:   File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 338, in _handle__invocation_request
    self.__run_sync_func, invocation_id, fi.func, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 470, in __run_sync_func
    return func(**params)
  File "/home/site/wwwroot/ManagedIdenityTester/__init__.py", line 33, in main
    connection = pyodbc.connect(odsConnectStr)
```

Here is a code snippet:

```
import pyodbc, logging
def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    logging.info(
        '+++++++++++++++++++++ Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.'
    )
    odsConnectStr = "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:my-server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=my_db;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryMsi"
    logging.info(f'--------- {odsConnectStr}')
    connection = pyodbc.connect(odsConnectStr)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        logging.info(f'--------- {row[0]}')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

So can anyone help on how I can connect to Azure SQL by my Azure Function using the managed identity?

PS: I have followed all the steps to enable system identity and also have created the external user within Azure SQL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Azure MSI to connect Azure SQL in Azure function with python, you can use Azure MSI to get Azure AD access token then you can use the token to connect AzureSQL. But please note that before you use the MSI to connect Azure SQL, you need to add the MSI as Azure SQL Database contained user and configure the needed SQL permissions for the MSI.

For example

1. [Enable system-assigned identity for your Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=python#using-the-azure-portal)
2. [Add the MSi as contained users in your Azure SQL database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities)

   a. Connect your SQL database with Azure SQL AD admin (I use [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#using-an-azure-ad-identity-to-connect-using-ssms-or-ssdt) to do it)

   b. run the following the script in your database

```
 CREATE USER <your app service name> FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
      // configure read and write permissions for the MSI
       ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER <your app service name>
       ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER <your app service name>
```

3. Code

```
import os
import pyodbc
import requests 
import struct

#get access token
identity_endpoint = os.environ["IDENTITY_ENDPOINT"]
identity_header = os.environ["IDENTITY_HEADER"]
resource_uri="https://database.windows.net/"
token_auth_uri = f"{identity_endpoint}?resource={resource_uri}&api-version=2019-08-01"
head_msi = {'X-IDENTITY-HEADER':identity_header}
resp = requests.get(token_auth_uri, headers=head_msi)
access_token = resp.json()['access_token']

accessToken = bytes(access_token, 'utf-8');
exptoken = b"";
for i in accessToken:
        exptoken += bytes({i});
        exptoken += bytes(1);
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken;

conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:<>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<>", attrs_before = { 1256:bytearray(tokenstruct) });

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select @@version")
row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row:
        logging.info(f'--------- {row[0]}')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity)

Comment: Where do the os.environ objects come from?

Comment: @JohnStud, that is one of the ways to store the secrets, credentials. Once can first create environment variables where he can store the credentials, and then read them using os.environ['<env_variable_key>']. Thus you don't need to store them in a file in an unprotected way.